# Объединить запросы MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть один SQL запрос:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1");
```

И есть второй SQL запрос:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `tasks` WHERE `author_id` = 1");
$num = $db->num($query);
```

Первым запросом я получаю имя пользователя, вторым количество его записей из таблицы tasks.

Можно ли как-то объединить всё это в 1 запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю во втором запросе у вас пропущен COUNT(*).
Так как у вас MySQL, то вытащить данные одним запросом думаю возможно.
Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.*) cnt, u.first_name FROM users u JOIN tasks t ON t.author_id = u.id WHERE u.id = 1;
```